# What does this picture on my helmet mean?

Tags: helmets

This was on a label on the side of my new Abus helmet. Does anyone know what it means?

[image: picture]

Comment: It means rotate 90° clockwise to unlock. Is there anything near the label that would apply to?

Comment: That is exactly my question. It says I need to turn 90 degrees right to unlock, but I have no clue as to what there is to unlock. In the rear there is a little wheel, that makes the helmet tighter or looser, but that does not lock, afaik.

Comment: Probably from the packaging or another item

Comment: It was attached to the helmet, I had to cut it off.

Comment: Is there a model on the helmet?   I've explored https://www.abus.com/uk/Mobile-Security/Bike-Safety-and-Security/Helmets/Helmets-and-technologies and there's no mention of any rotate-to-lock function.

Comment: Not on bike helmets, but I have seen plastic twist fasteners used to hold things in their packaging. How was it packed?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the exact model of helmet, please? Then we can check if it can have lights attached, or the strap removed, as possible candidates for something to unlock.

Comment: Abus Airbreaker.

Comment: The only thing I can see in the [user guide](https://www.abus.com/var/ImagesPIM/abus_kg/WEB%20PDF%20Dateien/Bedienungsanleitungen/Mobile%20Sicherheit/Fahrrad/helmets/ABUS_Helmets_Airbreaker_BDA_148x105mm.pdf) would be what looks like a clip in figure 4 that you would lift to release the swatooth-shaped retainer, but even then I'm not sure from that picture - is there a related part on the straps?

Comment: *sawtooth-shaped

Comment: On the user manual you posted, in the top right there's pictures of the string in the lining, that end in an attachment to the helmet. There's three holes you can put them in. You need to turn the strap 90 degrees, take it out, put it in another hole, then lock it by turning it 90 degrees. You post that as the answer, I'll accept. You provided the info.

Comment: @Christine It would probably be best if you wrote the answer as you can add a photo of the relevant part of the helmet.